# Make my LinearLayout act like a button

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a linear layout with custome views inside it and would like them to act like a button, so highlight itself when it is pressed.

I looked into Drawable resources but cant quite understand how it is done.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, do you require a click event on these custom views or are you asking how to "highlight" this custom view when pressed?

Comment: Well in the future, I will be tying on onClick event to it but for now I just want the "highlighting"

Comment: DHT is asking if you want each custom view to be highlighted when it's pressed or do you want the whole LinearLayout background to be highlighted when anything inside it is pressed. Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, just the custom view

Answer (score 2):

Create `selector.xml` file in `res/drawable/` folder

add next code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW_PRESSED_BACKGROUND" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW_NORMAL_BACKGROUND" />
</selector>
```

In your custom view add `android:background="@drawable/selector"`

Comment: How does that highlight it though?

Comment: First <item ... /> means that your custom view will have YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW_PRESSED_BACKGROUND when it is pressed.
For understanding of selector implement this tutorial http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/imagebutton/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Comment: All views have "state" properties. Views can be selected or unselected, pressed or normal, active/inactive, checked/un-checked etc. A selector looks at the current "State" of the view and chooses the appropriate drawable to use at that time.